# Put sticky hyphens in text input

Tags: html, css, angular

I need to put sticky hyphens in a text input. I attached an image of what I need. I have marked in red what should be fixed. The first hyphen should be after three number gaps, the next after two gaps, and so on.

The numbers appear as I click on each number but I want the dashes to appear by default.

I have tried to do it with a span but I have not succeeded.

```
     <div class="row">
        <p id="p" style="font-size: 30px;">Introduzca ubicación:<input style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 30px;"
            type="text" [value]="codeNum" id="code" placeholder="___-__-__-__-__">
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 30px; border: white 3px solid;"
            class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" (click)="clear()">Borrar</button>
          <button type="button" style="margin-left: 10px; font-size: 30px; border: white 3px solid;"
            class="btn btn-dark btn-lg" (click)="allClear()">Borrar todo</button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="calculator-keys">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('0')" value="0">0</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('1')" value="1">1</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('2')" value="2">2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('3')" value="3">3</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('4')" value="4">4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('5')" value="5">5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('6')" value="6">6</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('7')" value="7">7</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('8')" value="8">8</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-light waves-effect" (click)="pressNum('9')" value="9">9</button>
    </div>
```

[image: My image]

Thank you

Comment: can you provide relevant js as well [mcve]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom Angular Input Mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54765939/custom-angular-input-mask)

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using packages there's some out there that might fit your needs. E.g. [ngx-mask](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mask)

```
npm i --save ngx-mask
```

then you can do

```
<input type="text" mask="000-00-00-00-00" [(ngModel)]="codeNum">
```

OR

```
<p>{{ codeNum | mask: '000-00-00-00-00' }}</p>
```

Example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngx-mask-example-zd89hh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html